# PHP server time is different from client

Tags: php, time

On my PHP server I have a page that displays the time (hour:minutes). The time displayed on "today.php" matches the time of the machine.

BUT when I call that page from the browser of another PC on the network, it displays the time from a different timezone.

I want that page to display the same time for everyone.

I guess it has something to do with my php.ini, but I don't know how to fix it.

----Details of php.ini----

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = UTC
```

----Details of php.ini----

Comment: If you're generating the time in PHP, it won't matter what computer you're on. Sounds like you may actually be doing this in JavaScript? Show the code that generates the time on the page.

Comment: What's the code of today.php?

Comment: I get the time in php, not Js (because this is a time management app and I don't want users to cheat).                  
PHP CODE ----            
function db_now() {
 global $g_db;

 return time();
}
$hh = date( 'H',db_now() );
$mi = date( 'i',db_now() );
$jj = date( 'd',db_now() );
$mm = date( 'm',db_now() );

Answer (score 0):

If on the same server the time shouldn't change regardless of which browser/client accesses it. Could it be you're showing the time in Javascript instead perhaps?

Or is the php script on multiple servers?

IF the timezone is wrong on your server you can set it either in that php.ini file (if you have access) - alternatively you can do it in each script using ini_set... e.g.:

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/London');
```

That would work for the UK.
Alternatively you can find your correct timezone on: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: I get the time in php, not Js (because this is a time management app and I don't want users to cheat).
PHP CODE ----
function db_now() {
 global $g_db;

 return time();
}
$hh = date( 'H',db_now() );
$mi = date( 'i',db_now() );
$jj = date( 'd',db_now() );
$mm = date( 'm',db_now() );

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do this in PHP? For display on the client side with the [JavaScript Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) you can use:

```
<script language="javascript">
userDate = new Date();
document.write(userDate.toLocaleString());
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Resolved!
I found out that each user in that application can choose his own timezone, which explains my problem.

Thk you all

Comment: Do not declare your comments as answer, Use comments to inform, if it works.